# "Notebook" or "workbook"?

Tags: word-choice

What's a proper word to use for an item without any printed words, where pupils, for example, may write compositions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following words refer to books without printed text, usually of the lined variety:

- [*notebook*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notebook) (mostly US)
- [*exercise book*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exercise_book) (mostly UK and related countries)
- [*composition book*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_book) (a specific variety of notebooks)

A [*workbook*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workbook) has printed texts (for the exercises), and so will not fall into this classification. Note that an *exercise book* can also mean a *workbook* in American usage, although this is rare.

Comment: thank you very much! So now I understand, a notebook and an excersice book mean the same, but notebook is mostly used in the USA and excersice book - in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

It is often called a *composition book*.  If you don't like that, I would use note book (for taking notes) that than work book (examples of which often include questions with blanks for you to fill in the answer).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I've thought! It's a shame that many my colleagues including my boss don't agree with such definition. They still use "work-book" in the situation discribed above. But what's the difference between a "workbook" and "excersice-book" is?

Comment: And I've never thought about using a "composition book"! Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, to this American "composition book" sounds very old-fashioned.

Comment: @Valentina - you're right, _exercise book_ is more commonplace than _composition book_.  An _exercise book_ is where you write down the answers to _exercises_.  It is more likely to be a set of blank pages than a _work book_ which is likely to include the questions/exercises too.

Comment: Ok, and a "copy-book" is for small kids for them to copy letters and words, right?